# Selecting only numeric columns from a data frame

Tags: r

Suppose, you have a data.frame like this:

```
x <- data.frame(v1=1:20,v2=1:20,v3=1:20,v4=letters[1:20])
```

How would you select only those columns in x that are numeric?

Answer (score 378, accepted):

EDIT: updated to avoid use of ill-advised `sapply`.

Since a data frame is a list we can use the list-apply functions:

```
nums <- unlist(lapply(x, is.numeric), use.names = FALSE)
```

Then standard subsetting

```
x[ , nums]

## don't use sapply, even though it's less code
## nums <- sapply(x, is.numeric)
```

For a more idiomatic modern R I'd now recommend

```
x[ , purrr::map_lgl(x, is.numeric)]
```

Less codey, less reflecting R's particular quirks, and more straightforward, and robust to use on database-back-ended tibbles:

```
dplyr::select_if(x, is.numeric)
```

Newer versions of dplyr, also support the following syntax:

```
x %>% dplyr::select(where(is.numeric))
```

Comment: `x[nums]` or `x[sapply(x,is.numeric)]` works as well. And they always return `data.frame`. Compare `x[1]` vs `x[,1]` - first is `data.frame`, second is a vector. If one want to prevent conversion then must use `x[, 1, drop=FALSE]` .

Comment: Any way to select continuous data only? This method returns continuous as well as integer.

Comment: When there is no numeric column, the following error arise `undefined columns selected`. How do you avoid it ?

Comment: @SoilSciGuy continuous data should be as.numeric. Perhaps you have factor data that's in numeric form? You should open a new question.

Comment: @YohanObadia You can use a `tryCatch()` to deal with this. Please consider opening a new question.

Comment: @SoilSciGuy `x[sapply(x, is.numeric) & ! sapply(x, is.integer)]`

Comment: why if I do that with apply(data,2,is.numeric) it does not work, even if the output is identical to unlist(lapply(x, is.numeric)) @mdsummer

Comment: apply is for arrays, not for data frames that can have columns of different types - if you apply() you get all columns the same type, and so some are character and then all are character

Answer (score 97):

The dplyr package's `select_if(`) function is an elegant solution:

```
library("dplyr")
select_if(x, is.numeric)
```

Comment: select_if has been superseded, any idea how to do this with the current version?

Comment: select(where(is.numeric)) https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/where.html

Answer (score 59):

`Filter()` from the base package is the perfect function for that use-case:
You simply have to code:

```
Filter(is.numeric, x)
```

It is also much faster than `select_if()`:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
    dplyr::select_if(mtcars, is.numeric),
    Filter(is.numeric, mtcars)
)
```

returns (on my computer) a median of 60 microseconds for `Filter`, and 21 000 microseconds for `select_if` (350x faster).

Comment: This solution doesn't fail when no numeric columns are present. Are there any drawbacks to using it?

Comment: Filter only applies to rows of a dataframe rather than columns. As such, this solution wouldn't give the correct result.

Comment: @Michael don't confuse Filter from the base package and filter from dplyr package!

Comment: @bli I can't see any drawback of using Filter. Its input is a data.frame object and it return a data.frame

Comment: Just chiming in here for reference: what ```Filter()``` doesn't work for here is replacing, e.g. ```Filter(is.numeric,iris) <- 0.5*Filter(is.numeric,iris)``` won't work.

Comment: This one also works with data.table, thx!

Answer (score 9):

in case you are interested only in column names then use this :

```
names(dplyr::select_if(train,is.numeric))
```

Answer (score 9):

```
iris %>% dplyr::select(where(is.numeric)) #as per most recent updates
```

Another option with `purrr` would be to negate `discard` function:

```
iris %>% purrr::discard(~!is.numeric(.))
```

If you want the names of the numeric columns, you can add `names` or `colnames`:

```
iris %>% purrr::discard(~!is.numeric(.)) %>% names
```

Comment: negating `discard()` is pretty much the same as using `keep()`.

Answer (score 8):

This an alternate code to other answers:

```
x[, sapply(x, class) == "numeric"]
```

with a `data.table`

```
x[, lapply(x, is.numeric) == TRUE, with = FALSE]
```

Comment: This is more of a comment to the selected answer, rather than aunique answer.

Comment: Columns can have more than one class.

Answer (score 6):

```
library(purrr)
x <- x %>% keep(is.numeric)
```

Answer (score 3):

The library PCAmixdata has functon splitmix that splits quantitative(Numerical data) and qualitative (Categorical data) of a given dataframe "YourDataframe" as shown below:

```
install.packages("PCAmixdata")
library(PCAmixdata)
split <- splitmix(YourDataframe)
X1 <- split$X.quanti(Gives numerical columns in the dataset) 
X2 <- split$X.quali (Gives categorical columns in the dataset)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have many factor variables, you can use `select_if` funtion.
install the dplyr packages. There are many function that separates data by satisfying a condition. you can set the conditions.

Use like this.

```
categorical<-select_if(df,is.factor)
str(categorical)
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this earlier answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40808873/170352

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be as follows:-

```
#extracting numeric columns from iris datset
(iris[sapply(iris, is.numeric)])
```

Comment: Hi Ayushi, this probably was downvoted because it's a repeat of the first answer, but this method has some issues that were identified. Take a look at the comments in the first answer, you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
Numerical_variables <- which(sapply(df, is.numeric))
# then extract column names 
Names <- names(Numerical_variables)
```

Comment: Hey Mo! I recommend you try this in the console because I don't think it's going to give you what you think it will.

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't directly answer the question but can be very useful, especially if you want something like all the numeric columns except for your id column and dependent variable.

```
numeric_cols <- sapply(dataframe, is.numeric) %>% which %>% 
                   names %>% setdiff(., c("id_variable", "dep_var"))

dataframe %<>% dplyr::mutate_at(numeric_cols, function(x) your_function(x))
```