# Selecting Columns in R using list and names

Tags: r, subset, reshape2

I found this question which was helpful in subsetting a DF for numeric columns only.

[Selecting only numeric columns from a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863097/selecting-only-numeric-columns-from-a-data-frame)

However I can't figure out how to do numeric columns PLUS any other columns.

I've tried:

```
nums <- sapply(df, is.numeric)
df <- df[, c(nums, "charcolumn")]
```

and:

```
df <- df[,c(sapply(df, is.numeric), "Pop_Size_Group")]
```

both of which gave me an "undefined columns selected error"

I understand that the sapply function gives me a list of TRUE/FALSE.  How can I subset my df to include all numeric columns PLUS additional columns I identify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe selecting `names` and concatenating them with `"Pop_Size_Group"`

```
 df <- df[,c(names(df)[sapply(df, is.numeric)], "Pop_Size_Group")]
```