# Function to return the mean of type numeric

Tags: r, function, types, numeric

I have a df that has different fields and each field has different data type: date, numeric, factors, etc. For example:

```
ID<- c(1,2,3)
AGE <- c(25,32,28)
SEX <- c(1,0,0)
HEIGHT <- c(152,172, 163)
WEIGHT <-c(65,53,70)
DF<-data.frame(ID, AGE, SEX, HEIGHT, WEIGHT)
```

I have several datasets like this one, therefore I would like to create a function that would return a summary. This summary would be composed of the mean of the field, only when the field is numeric and the number of levels if the field is a factor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting only numeric columns from a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863097/selecting-only-numeric-columns-from-a-data-frame)

Comment: All the types in your example data are numeric. Could you give an example corresponding to the problem (_i.e._ one with different types).

Comment: Make sure that your column types are specified in your `data.frame`. For instance, "ID" and "SEX" should be `factor`s (or at least `character`s). Then you can use something like: `sapply(DF, function(x) if (is.numeric(x)) mean(x) else length(unique(x)))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constraint of "number of levels if the field is a factor" is a bit simplifying. What if a field is `character`? `logical`?

First example. I'll add a vector of `factor`:

```
FAC <- c('abc','abc','def')
DF <- data.frame(ID, AGE, SEX, HEIGHT, WEIGHT, FAC)
lapply(DF, function(x) if (is.numeric(x)) mean(x) else length(levels(x)))
# $ID
# [1] 2
# $AGE
# [1] 28.33333
# $SEX
# [1] 0.3333333
# $HEIGHT
# [1] 162.3333
# $WEIGHT
# [1] 62.66667
# $FAC
# [1] 2
```

If you need to be more controlling, perhaps you could extend it with:

```
lapply(DF, function(x) {
  if (is.logical(x)) x <- 1*x                    # turns into numeric, will show percentage of TRUE
  if (is.numeric(x)) return(mean(x))             # mean
  if (is.factor(x)) return(length(levels(x)))    # number of levels
  if (is.character(x)) return(length(unique(x))) # number of distinct strings, similar to levels
  if (inherits(x, "POSIXct")) return(min(x))     # min date/time
  return("oops")
})
```

You could certainly combine some, such as `is.numeric(x) || is.logical(x)` or even `is.numeric(x) || inherits(x, "POSIXct)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ID<- factor(c(1,2,3))

AGE <- c(25,32,28)
SEX <- factor(c('Male','Female','Male'))
HEIGHT <- c(152,172, 163)
WEIGHT <-c(65,53,70)

DF<-data.frame(ID, AGE, SEX, HEIGHT, WEIGHT)

# df_summary <- function(df) {
#   col_types <- sapply(df,class)
#   return(col_types)
# }

df_summary <- function(df) {
  numeric_cols <- df[,which(sapply(df, class) == "numeric")]
  numeric_means_df <- data.frame('Mean' = sapply(numeric_cols,mean))
  factor_cols <- df[,which(sapply(df,class) == 'factor')]
  factor_cols_summary <- summary(factor_cols)
  return(list('Numeric' = numeric_means_df,'Factors' = factor_cols_summary))

}

print(df_summary(DF))
```

[image]