# Select columns with a custom class

Tags: r, class, select, filtering, r-haven

The question is very straightforward. I am using the `haven` package, which creates a custom class called `haven_labelled` when importing data from Stata into R (which has the benefit of displaying labels in R). I would like to select columns which have this custom class (or any other custom class).

With the standard classes one would use `is.numeric`, `is.factor` etc.

For example: `df <- Filter(is.numeric, df)`.

Many other ways of doing this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863097/selecting-only-numeric-columns-from-a-data-frame).

I have tried substituting these examples with `class=="haven_labelled"`.

For example: `df <- Filter(class=="haven_labelled", df)`,
 but that does not work. It gives the error:

```
Error in class == "haven_labelled" : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

When trying H 1's solution, I figured out two things which might be important to anyone else using the haven package.

1. The class name actually has to be "labelled" as opposed to "haven_labelled".
2. The selection does not work because haven creates double classes for each variable (and all of them are `labelled` in addition to another class). Hence selection based on labelled just returns the full dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple function to test if something is of class "haven_labelled" and then use it to subset your data. For example:

```
is.haven <- function(x) "haven_labelled" %in% class(x)

Filter(is.haven, df)
```

or

```
df[sapply(df, is.haven)]
```

or

```
dplyr::select_if(df, is.haven)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear response and multiple solutions. When trying your solutions I figured out two things which might be important to anyone else using the `haven` package. 1. The class name actually has to be `"labelled"` as opposed to "haven_labelled". 2. The selection does not work because haven creates double classes for each variable (and all of them are `labelled` in addition to another class). Hence selection based on `labelled` just returns the full dataset.