# How to select columns of a particular datatype in R: select_dtypes equivalent in r

Tags: r

I am new to R. I am good with python. In python we have a function `select_dtypes(df,include='datatype', exclude='datatype')`

So if I want to find out all numeric columns, I can do `select_dtype(df,include='numeric')` and I get list of numeric columns only. This will select all columns which are numeric(float, int32, int64 etc.) . I can also explicitly select only int columns and so on. Similarly I can also exclude  columns of a particular datatype

How do I achieve the same in R.

```
df

Int1  Int2   Char1   Char2  factor1  flaot1   #lets say these are the columns of a df
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting only numeric columns from a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863097/selecting-only-numeric-columns-from-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `select_if` from `dplyr` after reading the data into `R`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     select_if(is.numeric)
```

Or if we need to negate

```
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
     select_if(negate(is.numeric))
```

Or

```
df1 %>%
    select_if(~ !is.numeric(.))
```

---

Or in `base R`, we can check with `sapply`

```
i1 <- sapply(df1, is.numeric)
df1[i1]
```

If we need to exclude, negate (`!`)

```
df1[!i1]
```

Or with `Filter`

```
Filter(is.numeric, df1)
```

Or `Negate`

```
Filter(Negate(is.numeric), df1)
```

With a reproducible example

```
Filter(Negate(is.factor), iris)
```

Comment: pls include exclude too...how to exclude columns of a particular datatype

Comment: hi error: could not find function "negate"...can you tell me which is the library? i have used funprog...your first negate was with small n it seems..error solved

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor sorry, forgot.  it is from `purrr` updated