# Extract all columns except numeric in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, isnumeric

In my project, I want to extract all the columns except numeric from my R data frame, as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863097/selecting-only-numeric-columns-from-a-data-frame) question I used the same method and just put a not gate into `is.numeric()` R function but it is not working

This gives all the numaric data,

```
x<-iris %>% dplyr::select(where(is.numeric))
```

But this does not work as expected,

```
x<-iris %>% dplyr::select(where(!is.numeric))
```

**Note:** Finally the output data frame should only contain the species column in the iris dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`purrr` package from `tidyverse` serves exactly what you want by `purrr::keep` and `purrr::discard`

```
library(purrr)

x <- iris %>% keep(is.numeric)
```

by these piece of code, you set a logical test in `keep` function and only the columns which passed the test stays.

to reverse that operation and achieve to your wish, you can use `discard` from `purrr` also;

```
x <- iris %>% discard(is.numeric)
```

you can think `discard` as `keep` but with `!is.numeric`

or alternatively by `dplyr`

```
x <- iris %>% select_if(~!is.numeric(.))
```

Comment: qual <- df %>% select_if(~!is.numeric(.)) is also worked for me if you can update the answer with this it would be more useful for somebody